# Using null while adding SQL parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I would like to add some null's to table:

```
command.CommandText =
"INSERT into clients (Addres, companyID) VALUES (@Addres, @companyID) ; select SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addres", null);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyID", null);
```

Table dessign allows null's. Why I have this error then?

```
The parameterized query '(@Addres nvarchar(4000),@companyID nvarchar(4000))INSERT into cl' expects the parameter '@Addres', which was not supplied.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addres", DBNull.Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyID", DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: Documentation link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `DBNull` class for null values in SQL. Your code will be like this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addres", DBNull.Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyID", DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlstring.null%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addres", System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyID", System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null);
```

Read: [Handling Null Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172138(v=vs.110).aspx)

`DBNull.Value` can be used for any type as opposed to [`SqlTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It can be handy to make the code more readable and type-safe, for example:

```
var addrVal = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString(someAddress);
// ...
if (condition) addrVal = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addres", addrVal);
```

Comment: What if the parameter is not a string?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: but in this case it is a string, both are `nvarchar`, that's why i have used it. If it's an `int`(for example): `SqlInt32.Null`. It's the "type safe" version.

Comment: I just wanted to have that mentioned :-D